# Get ordered list of parent-children in order in single query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child

I have a table called `comments`.   There are three columns here that are relevant:

`id, parent_id, create_date`.

The parent comments have a `parent_id` of 0 by default.  Each child has a `parent_id` of the parent's `id`. (Obvious stuff thus far)

I am looking for a single SQL query that will order it like this:

- First, by the parent's `create_date DESC`
- Second, each child underneath the parent (if a child exists), by `create_date DESC`

An example:

1. Parent Comment, 1 day ago

   1. Newest Child comment 1 hour ago
   2. Second Newest Child comment 3 hours ago
2. Parent Comment, 3 days ago

   1. First Child Comment, 1 hour ago

Is this possible to do in a single query?  Currently I am I am using php nested loops and this is very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to use both dates (record date and record's parent date) for sorting

```
SELECT *
  FROM (   SELECT c1.id,
                  c1.parent_id,
                  c1.create_date ac,
                  c1.create_date ap
             FROM comments c1
            WHERE parent_id = 0
           UNION
           SELECT c2.id,
                  c2.parent_id,
                  c2.create_date ac,
                  p.create_date ap
             FROM comments c2
             JOIN comments p
               ON c2.parent_id = p.id) c
 ORDER BY c.ap, c.ac;
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbbe4/2)